# Inserting *.dat file in new client

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat

I'm running out of ideas and I'm hoping to get some help.
My computer crashed but I have the wallet.dat file on a thumb drive. I've downloaded and synced v0.18.1 on a new computer but don't see any way to add the .dat file using the GUI. Do I have to use the command line prompts? If so, the proper procedure would be very helpful. 
I did see a similar situation on this forum but the advice given was over my head.
Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: You can just copy it to the bitcoin directory. What OS are you using?

Comment: Thank you so much JBaczuk for responding.

I finally figured out how to get to the directory; replaced the wallet.dat file with my saved file and it's now running and showing the proper balance.

It could be a bit easier process for us non-computer guys. :)
BTW, using Windows 10

Comment: great, agreed an entire wallet import feature would be nice.